# ICU4j - How to override the currency symbol or add customized currency with Numberformatter

Tags: java, locale, icu, currency-formatting, icu4j

I want to override the currency symbol. For example, ICU only returns `BGN 0.67` with currencyCode `BGN` no matter which options I use (`Narrow`, `Short`, and `VARIANT` in [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/index.html?com/ibm/icu/number/NumberFormatter.UnitWidth.html)) for `en` locale, but I would like to get `лв 0.67`. We also have other use cases to override the currency symbol.

`com.ibm.icu.util.Currency` doesn't provide any set functions to do the override. When `Numberformatter` appends the currency symbol to a number, it calls `getName` method to get currency symbol in Currency.java

```
public String getName(ULocale locale, int nameStyle, boolean[] isChoiceFormat) {
  ...
  CurrencyDisplayNames names = CurrencyDisplayNames.getInstance(locale);
  switch (nameStyle) {
    case SYMBOL_NAME:
      return names.getSymbol(subType);
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

`CurrencyDisplayNames` has predefined data, and doesn't provide any method to do the override.

I found `Numberformat` can override the currency symbol through `Numberformat.getCurrencyInstance()`, but ICU suggests the new users to use `Numberformatter`, so how do I do the symbol override, or other override like put dollar sign on the right of the number for a certain locale? (Most of the output ICU formats are good to us, but we want to customize for a currency under a certain locale)